# New install has a login loop

Tags: system-installation

I am a new elementary OS user and I just installed it on a PC.

The installation took place as normal. However, when I put the password in and it begins to login after 3 seconds the screen goes black and back to screen users.

Comment: Hello, welcome to community, did this behaviour occur just after the installation?

Comment: Did you install anything before this happend?

Comment: I have the same Problem but everytime i writen one of These Commands i became this answer: „command sed is in /bin/sed aviable
The command could not be found because usr is not part of the environment variable PATH .“ How i can fix this Problem?

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the terminal with your username and password. Your password will not show `*` or anything, but it is being typed.

Now run `ls ~ -lah` to list files in your home folder. If in the output the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

appears then your .Xauthority file has the wrong permissions. You need to do `sudo chown $USER:$USER .Xauthority` and try logging in.

If you don't see that line, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly like so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

If they don't, you need to run the command `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

If neither of these work, I'd recommend you either

1. Run this command:

   ```
   dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   ```

   to reconfigure `lightdm` - the login manager.
2. Or uninstall `lightdm`, and reinstall it with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`

Now restart the computer with this command:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

and login again.

---

To prevent this issue in the future, don't run GUI (Graphical User Interface) programs with `sudo`. If you have to (for example to open the file manager) add the `-H` flag - so you run `sudo -H command-goes-here`.

Comment: Tim, can you edit this post to explain what each of these commands is intended to do? It would also be helpful to explain what the problem is, possible causes, and how to avoid those in the future.

Comment: @DanielForé done

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue... was going around in circles.. couldn't even load a usb installer to back end the HDD version..

it was a memory issue.. i logged through tty3 and cleared out my downloads and documents and hey presto.. i only wasted 3 hours of my life!

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck on the login form too. I just installed Elementary and this is my very first login attempt. I already checked my `.Xauthority` file: it is property of my personal user (not root). I also reinstalled `lightdm` but nothing changed. Someone has an hint for a linux noob like me? :D Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Like PierPaolo Zus, I have the same problem right now. It happened a few days ago after installing updates. I guess something in the update broke lightdm.

I have tried all the things proposed here.

What I did as a workaround is that I installed kde-full and sddm and then I use sddm as login manager and KDE as desktop environment. This is NOT a real solution. But it is a workaround that allows me to use my computer again.

I hope someone knows how to actually fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get past the lock screen by accessing alternative text-based shell session with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1/6</kbd> then switching between login managers, namely `lightdm` and `gdm3` by invoking `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` then pass your current `display manager`as the final argument. Finally reversed the same step back again.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading (including a new kernel which usually takes up a bit of space), I ran into the same problem. Freeing up some disk space as mentioned before did the trick. For this, I

1. Pressed *Ctrl* + *Alt* + *F1* on the login screen to open a TTY
2. Logged in
3. Ran `sudo apt autoremove` to purge old packages (confirm prompt)
4. Ran `reboot` to restart

This happened to remove some older Kernel version which freed up enough space for the login to work again.